# How to get correct time in utc using moment.js when the device time is set incorrectly?

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I set the mobile device time forward/backward say by 10 minutes and did moment.utc() to get utc timestamp. The received timestamp is not the correct one. It preserves forward/backward minutes. 
Any solution?

Comment: Not really - you'd need to do a call to an authoritative server that you trust to have the right time

Comment: The mobile device might be disconnected during the call. It preserves the time stamp and will send the time stamp later to the server.

Comment: At the end of the day, you can't 100% trust anything from a client device.  If you need to know exactly when something happened (amongst other things - eg you surely wouldn't rely on client calculations of a shopping basket total), it needs to come from a server you control.