# How to get time in UTC independent of the device?

Tags: javascript, node.js, date, npm, momentjs

I am working in node.js where I have two scenarios:

1. To get UTC time at present
2. get UTC time of a future date which is set in local time.
   I have to convert both of these to my local time. I'm able to achieve this using javascript `new Date()` and moment.js `.tz()` function. But the `new Date()` is machine-dependent. I came across [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26739305/9756816) which suggests we can't even trust moment.js what can I use to get UTC time independent of the device/server.

Comment: Each device only knows what time it is according to its system clock. If that’s set wrong for whatever reason, yeah, it will be wrong. If that’s a concern, you must let a trusted server give you the time. That server's clock should be kept current with an NTP client.

Comment: @deceze is there an npm package to do the same?

Comment: Ha. Just send the time to the client from the server. No need for a package.

Comment: @CodyＧ What if for some reason the time of the server is incorrect?

Comment: That’s where you need to ensure an NTP client is running and keeps the server's clock current. That’s not really a job for an npm package, it’s a system level configuration.